# Excel/VBA uncheck checkboxes if mandatory field is empty

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I wrote a function which for each checkbox in document check if field C140 is empty if is then uncheck checkbox in same row.

```
Sub MarkCheckBoxes()

Dim chk As CheckBox
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

For Each chk In ws.CheckBoxes
    If ws.Range("C140").Value = "" Then
        chk.Value = False
    Else
        chk.Value = True
    End If
Next chk

End Sub
```

Now I want change it that for each row check if mandatory fields are empty if is then uncheck checkbox in the same row as empty field, also I need clean row color by:

```
EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
```

When I changed `range("c140")` to `range("c140:c150")` then I had an error mismatch..

ALSO

Ralph give me an answer for first part, but now I have another problem.

I'd like to make some function which allow me check if any of field in row 149 is text "Mandatory then it check if rows belows are empty if is then do uncheck. So I tried sth like this:

If ws.Rows("149") = "Mandatory" Then
If ws.Range("C" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value
But I don't have any idea how to write second if to check value in each column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you might be looking for something like this:

```
Sub MarkCheckBoxes()

Dim chk As CheckBox
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

For Each chk In ws.CheckBoxes
    If ws.Range("C" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Then
        chk.Value = False
    Else
        chk.Value = True
    End If
Next chk

End Sub
```

Explanations:
I changed merely the row for `C140` to `C` + the row number in which the checkbox is located. I hope this is what you've been looking for.

In respect to your initial attempt to change `Range("C140")` (which is one cell) to a range of cells like `C140:C150`: of course that cannot work. That would be like *please compare this apple to these 10 apples*. In return you would get 10 answers some of which might be true and others might be false for your `If` clause. VBA wouldn't know which ones of the `ture` or the `false` to take.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain me one thing more how to change color of entire row.
When i;m trying rn.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone With Set rn = ws.Cells("C" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row)
or chk.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone

I got error.

Comment: What is `rn`? Where is this coming from? It should be `ws.Range("C" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone` or `ws.Range("C" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 36` (to make the row yellow).

Comment: i solved it but i have problem with:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413625/excel-vba-find-cell-in-any-column-if-in-specific-row-is-required
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43411781/excel-vba-rows-and-column-if-statement/43411908?noredirect=1#comment73883163_43411908

Plz help:)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Cells property of the Worksheet instead of the Range like this in your If statent:

```
If ws.Cells(3, chk.TopLeftCell).Value = ""
```